# Timeout Exception during call from wpf client to server in one solution

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf

What is the problem: System.TimeoutException: 'The request channel timed out while waiting for a reply after 00:00:59.977913. So, basically it can be everything.

What do I have:

I create a simple solution to found a fix. What really make me confused is that console app works just fine, however wpf app with same configuration does not work. Solution include four projects(code made for debugging purpose, please don't judge it):

1. library with contracts and their implementation.

   ```
   public class DeviceService : IDeviceService
   {
     public string GetDevices()
     {
       return "hello world";
     }
   } 

   [ServiceContract]
   public interface IDeviceService
   {
       [OperationContract]
       string GetDevices();
   }
   ```
2. library with host.

   ```
   public class DeviceServiceHostFactory
   {

     ServiceHost host;

     public DeviceServiceHostFactory()
     {
       ServiceMetadataBehavior metadataBehavior;

       BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();

       Uri address = new Uri("http://localhost:4000/");
       host = new ServiceHost(typeof(DeviceService), address);
       Type contract = typeof(IDeviceService);
       host.AddServiceEndpoint(contract, binding, "");
     }

     public void Start()
     {
       host.Open();
     }

     public void Stop()
     {
       host.Close();
     }
   }
   ```
3. desktop app that start service and consume it (does not work)

   ```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
      private DeviceServiceHostFactory _deviceService;

      public MainWindow()
      {
        InitializeComponent();

        try
        {
           _deviceService = new DeviceServiceHostFactory();
           _deviceService.Start();
        }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
           _deviceService.Stop();
           Console.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
       }
     }

     private void Btn_custom_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
     {
       BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
       EndpointAddress endpoint =
           new EndpointAddress("http://localhost:4000/");

       var factory =
           new ChannelFactory<IDeviceService>(
               binding, endpoint);

       var channel = factory.CreateChannel();
       txt_custom.Text = channel.GetDevices();

       Console.WriteLine();
     }
   } 

    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IDeviceService
    {
      [OperationContract]
      string GetDevices();
    }
   ```
4. console app (works fine)

   ```
   class Program
   {

     static void Main(string[] args)
     {
       DeviceServiceHostFactory _deviceService = new 
            DeviceServiceHostFactory();

      try
      {
           _deviceService.Start();

           BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
           EndpointAddress endpoint =
               new EndpointAddress("http://localhost:4000/");

           var factory =
               new ChannelFactory<IDeviceService>(
                   binding, endpoint);

           var channel = factory.CreateChannel();
           Console.WriteLine(channel.GetDevices());
           Console.ReadLine();
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
           _deviceService.Stop();
           Console.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
       }
     }
   }

   [ServiceContract]
   public interface IDeviceService
   {
     [OperationContract]
     string GetDevices();
   }
   ```

I really spend a lot of time for this, and I will be very grateful for every solution or thought how can I debug it more advanced.

Comment: Use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and compare the first request of working application with first request of non working application.   If the same then check the response.

Comment: In non working does the button click work?  You may not be getting to the code in the click.

Comment: @jdweng it gets there, exception thrown on channel.GetDevices() inside Btn_custom_Click. I try without button, it always thrown on channel.GetDevices()

Comment: Add a 10 second wait before you do GetDevices and see if the error still occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hosting wcf service in application with UI is little bit tricky, so I hope this will help someone.

Took it from book **Learning WCF: A hands-On Guide By Michele Leroux Bustamante, Chapter 4**, so fo more information please find this book.

To host service in Windows application or WPF application, we have to create a new thread to start it in a new synchronization context. It can be done in two ways:

First, is to create service host before the UI thread created. Here service executes in a new synchronization contenxt before application starts.

```
static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        DeviceServiceHostFactory deviceService = new DeviceServiceHostFactory();
        deviceService.Start();

        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new MainWindow);
    }
}
```

Second, is to initialize service host on a separate thread, after UI been created

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
 {

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Thread thread;
        thread = new Thread(ServiceInitialize); 
        thread.IsBackground = true;
        thread.Start();
    }

    private void ServiceInitialize()
    {       
        var service  = new DeviceServiceHostFactory();
        service.Start();
    }
 }
```

This means the messages are processed on threads form the thread pool instead of through the message loop.

Answer (score 0):

First, we should give the current account permissions when we occupy the Operation system ports to host services.
This function could be accomplished by the below command.

> Netsh http add urlacl url=https://+:80/MyUri user=DOMAIN\user

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/http/add-urlacl
If we don’t want to do this, we could directly run the service with administrator accounts.
Thereby I suspect there is something wrong with the process of hosting the service. Have you tried running the WPF application with an administrator account?
Besides, I suggest you add a namespace in the service contract.

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace ="MyNamespace")]
public interface IDeviceService
{
    [OperationContract]
    string GetDevices();
}
```

Sometimes, it could run into problems when the service contract doesn’t have a namespace property.
Feel free to let me know if the problem still exists.